# How do I improve the growth of this Ficus?

Tags: ficus

I've had this Ficus tree for some time now. The growth is a bit meek. The leafs are small, the color is not as deep green and not every branch/limb has them. If you can see on the right the other Ficus tree next to this one has excellent leafs. They are lush and deep green color.

I suspect perhaps I am doing something wrong with this tree. May be the soil isn't what it needs to be or may be something else.

Can someone help diagnose what might be wrong this this Ficus tree?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to be certain from the photograph,but it would appear that the pot your Ficus is in is way too small for it. The plant needs to develop a larger root system in order to support healthy and abundant topgrowth, and it's not able to do that currently. You can check by turning the plant out of its pot - if the root ball is solid with roots wrapping round and round the outside, then it needs a bigger container, with a drainage hole in the bottom.

Use new potting soil around the rootball when potting into a larger container.

Comment: I will re-pot and post updates. Thank you so much for you insight!